# MPI_Scatter segmentation fault (signal 11)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi

I'm trying to Parallelize some piece of code that calculates matrices, but I'm getting segmentation fault error. I already debug the code, but I cant find out the problem.

Here is the snippet where I declare the matrice:

```
double **A, **B, **C, *tmp1,*tmp2,*tmp3;
int N;
int myrank, P, from, to;

N = 100;

tmp1 = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double ) * N * N);
tmp2 = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double ) * N * N);
tmp3 = (double *) malloc (sizeof(double ) * N * N);
A = (double **) malloc (sizeof(double *) * N);
B = (double **) malloc (sizeof(double *) * N);
C = (double **) malloc (sizeof(double *) * N);

from = myrank * N/P;
to = (myrank+1) * N/P;
```

Then here is where I inicialize the MPI

```
MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &P);
```

But somehow, I can't scatter...

```
MPI_Bcast(B, N*N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("Rank: %d\n", myrank);

MPI_Scatter(A, N*N/P, MPI_INT, &A[from], N*N/P, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I can't wrote all the code here because I'm not allowed...But the problem is in Scatter it self. What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Consider making it as easy as possible for others to help you. i.e. do not dump snippets of seemingly unrelated code. And do not dump your entire program here. Instead, try to delete blocks of the code that are not relevant to the problem while still reproducing your bug. i.e. try to produce a [short, self contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/). Then paste that. What you've pasted here is so disconnected most people won't even feel like reading it.

Comment: Variable `P` is used without being initialized first!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly send a 2-D matrix (`double**`). Instead, you have to pass the address of the actual data: `&A[0][0]`. For receiving, you also have to pass an address to where the data is actually stored. In your case this would be: `&A[from][0]` instead of `&A[from]`.

Try this as the scatter:

```
MPI_Scatter(&A[0][0], N*N/P, MPI_INT, &A[from][0], N*N/P, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

On another note, on the receiving process all values in `A` other than those received will remain invalid. You might want to consider creating a separate receive buffer of the size required:

```
double* local_A = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N/P);
MPI_Scatter(&A[0][0], N*N/P, MPI_INT, local_A, N*N/P, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I already make that change, and now it works, but only for 1 processor. When I use 2 or more process's, i still have the segmentation fault error